# Spring Boot JUnit and @TestPropertySource using multiple property files

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit4

Spring Boot 2.0.3.RELEASE

Have more than one properties file to deal with .. the application.properties and application-DEV.properties

using the annotation @TestPropertySource in a Junit test I can only get it to read one file:

```
@TestPropertySource("file:C:\\Users\\user\\eclipse-workspace\\one2one_httpCall\\src\\main\\resources\\application-DEV.properties")
```

works as expected

However I need two properties file I did see the locations option but did not see an example of more than one file .. tried different options but none worked:

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-DEV.properties;classpath:application.properties")
```

Tried a couple of ways I am not posting and even tried using @TestPropertySource twice but error saying u cannot use it twice.

tried using @PropertySource since u can use it twice but did not work since this is a Junit test. Looked at a bunch of questions on stacktrace + others and tried but no luck.

So my question is how to use two properties files via the @TestPropertySource annotation?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you look inside the definition of `@TestPropertySource`, you will see that `locations` is of type `String []`. Therefore, if you need to pass it multiple values, you must do so with an array:

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = { "classpath:application.properties", "classpath:application-DEV.properties" })
```

Also, pay attention to the order in which you declare your properties files. As stated in the [TestPropertySource docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html#locations--):

> Each location will be added to the enclosing Environment as its own property source, **in the order declared**.

So you would probably want to declare your DEV properties **after** to avoid them being overriden by your production properties.